# Risch Algorithm for trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, integration, algorithms

I've implemented the transcendental Risch integration algorithm for logarithmic and exponential extensions ('classical Risch'). 
If I want to integrate functions containing trig-functions I have to convert them first to complex exponentials.

The problem is that the integration algorithm produces very 'ugly' results containing imaginary numbers, even if I convert the complex exponentials back to trig-functions.

Is there a way avoiding complex exponentials or a good way to simplify the expression after integration (maybe a tricky substitution)?

Comment: In short, yes, and Bronstein calls it the hypertangent case.

Comment: Yes, I know. But you have to solve a coupled system of differential equations. You have to modify the Risch DE solver so that it accepts tangent extensions. I wanted to know if there is a simple (maybe not the best) solution.